# Finding asymptotic growth using the Laplace Method

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, laplace-method

I am asked to find the  the asymptotic growth of the integral
$$I(k,m)=\int_0^1{x^{nk}}{{(1-x)}^{nm}}dx$$ with $k,m>0$ fixed.
How do I approach this solution? I know it means finding the growth as $n \to \infty$, but I am clueless on what to do. Does it have something to do with Stirling's approximation?

Comment: This is just a beta function, so the integral evaluated is a product/sum of gamma functions, where you can use Stirling’s approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually derive the behavior for large $n$, we begin by rewriting in Laplace's integral form
\begin{align}
I(k,m)& = \int_0^1{x^{nk}}{{(1-x)}^{nm}}dx \\
& = \int_0^1 e^{n[k \ln x + m \ln(1-x)]} \ dx.
\end{align}
Define $\phi(k,m,x)$ such that the integral is $e^{n\phi}$. This is maximal when $\partial \phi/\partial x = 0$ and is given by $x_c = \frac{k}{k+m}$. You can check this is maximal. Next we return to the integral and expand $\phi$ to second order.
\begin{align}
I(k,m)& = \int_0^1{x^{nk}}{{(1-x)}^{nm}}dx \\
& = \int_0^1 e^{n[k \ln x + m \ln(1-x)]} \ dx \\
& \approx \int_{x_c - \epsilon}^{x_c + \epsilon} e^{n[\phi(x_c) - \frac{1}{2}|\phi''(x_c)|(x-x_c)^2]} \ dx \\
& = e^{n \phi(x_c)} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} e^{-n|\phi''(x_c)|\frac{1}{2}u^2]} \ du \\
& = e^{n\phi(x_c)} \int_{-\sqrt{|\phi''(x_c)|n}}^{\sqrt{|\phi''(x_c)|n}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^2} \ \frac{ds}{\sqrt{|\phi''(x_c)|n}} \\
& \approx \frac{e^{-n\phi(x_c)}}{\sqrt{|\phi''(x_c)|n}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^2} \ ds \\
& = e^{-n\phi(x_c)}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{|\phi''(x_c)|n}}
\end{align}
You can insert the values for $\phi$ evaluated at $x_c$ to check against the asymptotics.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}$This is the [Beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

We have that:

$$I(k,m,n)=\B(nk+1,nm+1)=\frac{\Gamma(nk+1)\Gamma(nm+1)}{\Gamma(n(k+m)+2)}$$

Now you can use a Stirling approximation, as $\Gamma(x+1)=x!$, loosely speaking, and the Stirling series indeed provides an asymptotic formula for $\Gamma$.

$$\begin{align}I(k,m,n)&\sim\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{(nk)^{nk}(nm)^{nm}\cdot e^{n(k+m)+1}}{e^{n(k+m)}\cdot(n(k+m)+1)^{n(k+m)+1}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{(nk)(nm)}{n(k+m)+1}}\\&=e\sqrt{\frac{2\pi km}{k+m+\frac{1}{n}}}\cdot\frac{n^{n(k+m)+1/2}k^{nk}m^{nm}}{(n(k+m)+1)^{n(k+m)+1}}\\&=e\sqrt{\frac{2\pi\cdot km}{n(k+m)+1}}\cdot\frac{(k^km^m)^n}{\left(k+m+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n(k+m)+1}}\\&=e\sqrt{\frac{2\pi\cdot km}{n(k+m)+1}}\cdot\left(\frac{k^k\cdot m^m}{\left(k+m+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k+m+1/n}}\right)^n\end{align}$$

This approximation is strikingly accurate even for small $n$ due to the decaying nature of $I$. If you so wished you could have included more terms from the Stirling series for $\Gamma$.

Comment: Where does this use the Laplace Lemma? Thank you!

Comment: @Ifailedmaths I am not sure what you mean. If you mean Laplace’s precise approximation for integrals involving the Gaussian, then you can use that to prove Stirling’s approximation in the first place. However, if you take the Stirling-and-better approximations for the Gamma function as a given, you don’t need to use anything here at all other than the identity for the Beta function. If you are interested in such a proof of Stirling’s approximation I will send you a link.

Comment: @Ifailedmaths I’ll add that my updated approximation - the previous one was slightly wrong - is accurate even for $n$ as small as $10$, depending on $k$ and $m$ of course, since the integral is decaying fairly quickly to $0$.